# Iteratively join linestrings that intersect?

Tags: spatial-join, sf

I'm struggling to iteratively join intersecting linestrings of a geometry collection using `st_join`, meaning I want to join intersecting linestrings, but want to build on that join (i.e. joining all the linestrings that intersect in total).

Doing a reprex would be difficult for this, but curious if anyone has any suggestions.

The net results would be that one linestring joins to all its intersecting linestrings, and remains a linestring, not multiline, then that new line string joins to all intersecting line strings, and so forth until all line strings are consolidated if they intersect.

I've tried for loops and am just spinning wheels at this point. I realize this is not optimal for reproducibility, but figured I'd take a shot in the dark asking here.

Comment: I found an iterative solution using `st_join` on the dataset, `sysloop <- st_difference(st_join(sysloop, sysloop, join = st_intersects))` then `summarize` by id, `sysloop <- sysloop %>% group_by(gid) %>% summarize() %>% st_cast("MULTILINESTRING") %>% st_line_merge()` and using a `while` loopi until the joined id sum is equal. `while(sum(sysloop$gid.x) != sum(sysloop$gid.y))`